# How to avoid Duplicates in List.newBuilder Scala?

Tags: scala, builder

How do I avoid duplicates for this code:

```
val lastUpdatesBuilder = List.newBuilder[(String, Int)]
val somelist = List("a","a")

for (v <- somelist) {
  lastUpdatesBuilder += v -> 1
}

println(lastUpdatesBuilder.result())
```

Result is `List((a,1), (a,1))` and I want it to be List((a,1)) only.

Comment: Why can't you go with set? in place of List? I would suggest you not to use mutable variables, it's kind of anti pattern for scala.

Comment: Ohhh, why didn't I think of this!

Comment: your code is probably synthetic, but instead of mucking with builders, `yourlist.toSet.map(_ -> 1).toList` would get your list in a much more direct way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
object Demo extends App {
  val lastUpdatesBuilder = Set.newBuilder[(String, Int)]
  val somelist = List("a","a")

  for (v <- somelist) {
    lastUpdatesBuilder += v -> 1
  }

  println(lastUpdatesBuilder.result())
}
```

Tho i would suggest not to use mutable set you can do something like this.

```
val ans =  somelist.map{ key =>
    key -> 1
  }.toMap

  println(ans)
```

Or you can first remove the duplicate using `distinct` and then create a map out of it.

```
val somelist = List("a","a").distinct
val ans =  somelist.map{ key =>
    key -> 1
  }.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`distinct`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinct:C) method does.